# Parameter type inference breaks intersection?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

In the code below if type inference is used for the `do` parameter, the type system silently fails to generate the requested type intersection (i.e. I expect that the `create` function returns the intersection of `Obj` and `M` but if I use type inference in the `do` parameter I just get back an `Obj`). Is this a TS compiler bug or am I misunderstanding something?

```
type Effect<T, M> = {
  // NOTE: The problem seems to be here somewhere. Getting rid of the
  // intersection `& M` below gets rid of the error.
  do?: (o: T & M) => void;
};

type Obj = {};

function create<T, M>(params: {
  methods: M;
  effect: Effect<T, M>;
}): Obj & M {
  return params.methods
}

const obj = create({
  // If the parameter below is inferred then the Obj type
  // breaks and the methods are no longer merged in.
  // If a type is given (e.g. `obj:any`) the methods work
  // as expected
  effect:{do: (obj) => {}},
  methods: {
    something() {}
  }
});

// This will be an error if the effect infers the parameter type
obj.something();
```

[Here is a TS playground if you want to tinker with it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=17#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)

**Edit:** Pared down the code and focused the question. In the comments there's a reference to `ThisType` which was not the cause of the problem but was in the older version of the sample.

Comment: Not sure about that, but the line `methods: M & ThisType<FSM<T, C> & M>;` seems like something that may break easily, given the `M` inside and outside the generic. Have you already tried playing with it in order to fix it?

Comment: I agree it looks strange, but changing that does not affect the error and is pretty much pulled straight out of the Typescript documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#thistypet

Comment: Oh aweesome, thank you for pointing out! I’ll give another try :)